# How to remove some blocks from a sparse file on a ext2/ext3 filesystem

Tags: linux, filesystems

The ext2/ext3 filesystem automatically allocate blocks when you write a sparse file, but when I no longer want some blocks of them, I found no ways to do it. It feels like using malloc() without free().
Is it possible to "free" some blocks of a sparse file? If it is, how?
Don't tell me to copy it to a new file. It's too boring and needs a lot of disk space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Linux 2.6.38, there is a flag to [`fallocate`](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html) called `FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE` which should do what you want, i.e. deallocate file space at arbitrary locations.

```
fallocate(fd, FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE|FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE, offset, len);
```

will punch a hole into the file indicated by descriptor fd. The hole will start at `offset` and have length `len`, both measured in bytes. Only whole blocks will actually be removed, partial blocks will be zeroed out instead.

Comment: So this feature is finally added into Linux kernel. Thank you for answering my 3-year-old question. :D

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you can do is call ftruncate(), to remove blocks at the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Filesystems only allocate blocks for those parts of the sparse file that do in fact have any content. Removing *those* blocks would be pretty stupid because that’s your data. The other blocks can not be removed because they do not exist.

Comment: But there really exist situations that I don't want some blocks of a file any more and want to give the space back to the filesystem.

Answer (score -2):

Write zeroes to the portions you don't want.

Comment: This won't work, the block will now contain zeros instead of the 'hole' the original question is looking for.